# How do I get the most Accurate Altitude for Android Devices

Tags: android, gps, altitude

I am coding a Fitness tracking App right now. Therefore I want to use the Altitude. I know I can get the Altitude via GPS, but this seems far away from being accurate. I already tried my app on several devices and all of them had problems with their altitude.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: "this seems far away from being accurate" -- how have you determined this?

Comment: Well as I said I used the app on my device and I know at which Altitude I live, and the Phone was about 70 meters off... But when I use the strava fitness app the altitude is way better, so it must be possible somehow.

Comment: Without a [mcve] demonstrating how you have found the altitude, it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: GPS is terrible for altitude in this context.  Use the pressure sensor if you have one for the best you can get off a phone but there are limitations and you need a calibration strategy.  Fallback to online lookup or get the appropriate .dem files.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a google maps api, Google Maps Elevation API, which seems to provide the data you need, but apparently it does need a billing account associated, not sure if thats a possibility. But I would expect a company like Strava to use something like this, it seems pretty legit and accurate.

You make request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536,-104.9847034&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

and get something like this JSON back:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "elevation" : 1608.637939453125,
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 39.73915360,
            "lng" : -104.98470340
         },
         "resolution" : 4.771975994110107
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/start